# Calling a js.erb file with ajax in ruby on rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, erb

I have the following jQuery function that I'm trying to use with rails to create an alert on a page.

```
    $("#buttonID").click(function() {
      foo = $("#otherID").val();
      $.ajax({
        submitVar: foo //no idea what to do here
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'controller/action_js',
        dataType: 'script'
      });
    });
```

in my controller

```
    def action_js
      @item = Item.find(:name => foo)
      respond_to do |format|
        format.js
      end
    end
```

action_js.js.erb:

```
    alert(@item);
```

I'm trying to make it so that when I click the button with id = 'buttonID', an alert appears showing the item in the database whose name equals the value of the field with id = 'otherID'. I have no idea how to use js.erb properly with ajax or how to pass a variable to my js.erb file. Clicking the button currently does nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

`jQuery.getScript()` method to run it. See details, http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/

or

```
$.ajax({
    ..., 
    dataType: "script",
    ..
})
```

Both these above methods will fetch a script and then execute it.

Comment: Ok that is how you fetch and execute the script. Thank you. Is there any way to pass a variable either to the controller action or the js.erb file itself?

Comment: rails "params" hash will still have you GET or POST data, you can use that in the controller or view.

Comment: alright I got it working. thanks, mate. May your sword stay sharp and your steed be quick.